# Radare2 not showing memory value correctly

Tags: radare2, qemu

I am debugging a bootloader running on QEMU i386. 
[image: Screenshot]

The issue is the red value of 0x6069 shown as zero. In reality the value is the same as register al (non zero value) and the following je happens.

Is this a bug on R2 or am I missing some setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it is important to set the correct architecture. After setting

```
e asm.bits=32
e asm.arch=x86
```

everything works much better. Tested on r2 4.0.0.